# Importing data to a particular model

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, object, django-models

I'm starting with instances of `Order` object and trying to transform them into a JSON format, which will be used to update a table. I'm new to Django-specific code constructs.

My chosen approach is:

1. Load the data from database as multiple `Order` instances
2. Transform the `Order` instances into an intermediary `Table` object (the format is given)
3. Serialize the `Table` object into JSON

I have gone quite far so far, but I can't make the whole application run, except for running it in the Python shell. I have the models and serializers already in place.

Can someone offer his help how to mark all `Order` instances at once and transform them to `Table` in one API call and anything else that is missing in this simple example?

models.py:

```
# Order corresponds to Line in the Table
class Order(models.Model):
    doc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    nothing = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order

class Table(models.Model):
    pass

class Column(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

class Line(models.Model):
    doc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    nothing = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order
```

serializers.py:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    columns = ColumnSerializer(many=True)
    lines = LineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = [
            'columns',
            'lines'
        ]

class ColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = [
            'data'
        ]

class LineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = [
            'doc',
            'order',
            'nothing'
        ]
```

For this relational data:

```
doc         order       nothing
564251422   564210      5648
546546545   98745       4668
```

JSON output should be:

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "doc"
        },
        {
            "data": "order"
        },
        {
            "data": "nothing"
        }
    ],
    "lines": [
        {
            "doc": "564251422",
            "nothing": 0.0,
            "order": "56421"
        },
        {
            "doc": "546546545",
            "nothing": 0.0,
            "order": "98745"
        }
    ]
}
```

Shell commands:

```
import polls.models
polls.models.Order.objects.all() # outputs all orders
table = polls.models.Table()
polls.models.Column(data="doc",table=table)
polls.models.Column(data="order",table=table)
polls.models.Column(data="nothing",table=table)
polls.models.Line(doc="564251422",order="56421",nothing="0.0",table=table)
polls.models.Line(doc="546546545",order="98745",nothing="0.0",table=table)
```

views.py (**update**):

```
bunch = OrderSerializer(Order.objects.all(), many=True)                                                                              
headers = bunch.data[0].keys()                                                                                                                   
headers_prepared = map (lambda x: {'data': x} , headers)
ordered_all = ( ('columns', headers_prepared), ('lines', bunch.data) )
data = collections.OrderedDict(ordered_all)
data_json = JSONRenderer().render(data)
return JsonResponse(data_json, safe=False)
```

Comment: I saw that you are using the example of my answer that I gave you here : [django nesting serializers in each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957167/django-nesting-serializers-in-each-other). But Is this part working (Serialization and Deserialization)? You never talked about `Order` object, could you please tell us what do you want to do exactly (final goal) ?

Comment: It's a basic web application that should retrieve data from a database, then transform them into objects for internal processing (very important), the client should receive JSON data in the specified format that will be displayed in a table (also the format is specified). `Order` is used here because it is a business object that needs to be translated into something that can be displayed by the client (jQuery DataTables framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see this question may relate to another (mentioned in comments) , but for this particular case...

As you are using DjangoRestFramework (the right way), to get all data in Json format you may:

in *serialisers.py:*

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from polls.models import Order

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('doc', 'order', 'nothing')

# note we do not use other serializers
```

next in *shell* (views in future):

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from polls.models import Order
from polls.serializers import OrderSerializer

bunch = OrderSerializer(Order.objects.all(), many=True)

#this will output "lines" part of desired output
JSONRenderer().render(bunch.data)

#next to get columns, or i say headers
headers = bunch.data[0].keys() 
# headers = ['doc','order','nothing']
# !note will fail if bunch.data is empty

headers_prepared = map (lambda x: {'data': x} , headers)
# headers_prepared = [{'data': 'doc'}, {'data': 'order'}, {'data': 'nothing'}]

import collections # need to use OrderedDict to store in our sequence
ordered_all = ( ('columns', headers_prepared), ('lines', bunch.data) )

#finally desired output 
JSONRenderer().render( collections.OrderedDict(ordered_all)   )

#all code and output tested on my dummy data
```

**UPDATE** in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'my/', my),
    ...
]
```

add in views.py:

```
#as you sileny JSONResponse (from RestFramework docs) - need to show it 
from django.http import HttpResponse

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

#now our view

import collections 

def my(request):

    bunch = OrderSerializer(Order.objects.all(), many=True)

    # to get headers independent of presence of orders
    empty = OrderSerializer()
    headers = empty.data.keys()

    headers_prepared = map (lambda x: {'data': x} , headers)
    ordered_all = ( ('columns', headers_prepared), ('lines', bunch.data) )

    out = collections.OrderedDict(ordered_all)
    #finally desired output 
    return  JSONResponse( out  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it. This question expands on the other so that you know. Best way to describe the problem is that I want to serialize the `Order` in a particular format that is quite different from the source format I'm using the classes `Table`, `Column` and `Line` to help me achieve that.

Comment: Yep, you got the right output. when you call `JSONRenderer().render( collections.OrderedDict(ordered_all))` second time it doesn't output the column data, but it's just a detail. it would be interesting to see the views or how to do it outside of shell...

Comment: I got nearly to finish: `b'{"columns":[{"data":"doc"},{"data":"order"},{"data":"nothing"}],"lines":[{"doc":"564251422","order":"56421","nothing":"0.0"},{"doc":"546546545","order":"98745","nothing":"0.0"}]}' is not JSON serializable` is thrown when I `return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)`

Comment: Please double check your code or past it in comments as in my shell (django 1.8, python 2.7) it prints all data twice without any issues.

Comment: about 'not JSON serializable' you should delete penult line, and then last line will be return JsonResponse(data, safe=True)

Comment: the main problem was this `map (lambda x: {'data': x} , headers)`, I had to change to `list(map(lambda x: {'data': x} , headers))` to make it serializable, now works fine

Comment: It's probably not allowed in Python 3.4, not only on my machine